# Langchain huggngface text splitter can cause overflow the max token size

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers, py-langchain

It looks LangChain [Hugging Face tokenizer Text Splitter](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_transformers/text_splitters/split_by_token#hugging-face-tokenizer) is broken and cannot split a text into the token size below the max token length that model can accept.

Tokenization may not preserve the same word it had tokenized if tokens get chopped. For example, tokenizer of the model **all-MiniLM-L6-v2** will tokenize **8 trillions** into `['[CLS]', '8', 'trillion', '##s', '[SEP]']` where the plural **s** in **trillions** becomes a token, not part of the token of the word, hence a word can generate multiple tokens. This can cause an issue.

Suppose **8 trillions** is a part of a long text to split into multiple by counting its tokens.

1. tokenizes the long text including **8 trillions** as `['[CLS]', '8', 'trillion', '##s', '[SEP]']`.
2. split the tokens at `##s`.
3. restore the tokens of the split will make **##s** as a new word.
4. text split including **##s** is then re-tokenized into `['[CLS]', '#', '#', 's', '[SEP]']` as model inputs, adding two more token counts which can overflow the max token length.

```
from transformers import (
    AutoTokenizer,
    PreTrainedTokenizer
)

model_name: str = "all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
     f'sentence-transformers/{model_name}'
)
text = "8 trillions"
tokenizer.batch_decode(tokenizer(text)['input_ids'])
-----
['[CLS]', '8', 'trillion', '##s', '[SEP]']
```

```
tokenizer.batch_decode(tokenizer("##s")['input_ids'])
-----
['[CLS]', '#', '#', 's', '[SEP]']     # 's' is used to be one token as part of 'trillions', now become three.
```

It also assumes that the tokenizers generate the structure of `[start_token][tokens][end_token]` and use `[1:-1]` to truncate start_token and end_token.

[SentenceTransformersTokenTextSplitter](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/stable/_modules/langchain/text_splitter.html#SentenceTransformersTokenTextSplitter)

```
def split_text(self, text: str) -> List[str]:
def encode_strip_start_and_stop_token_ids(text: str) -> List[int]:
        return self._encode(text)[1:-1]     # <-----

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(
        chunk_overlap=self._chunk_overlap,
        tokens_per_chunk=self.tokens_per_chunk,
        decode=self.tokenizer.decode,
        encode=encode_strip_start_and_stop_token_ids,
    )

    return split_text_on_tokens(text=text, tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

However, this does not work because some model(s) may not always generate a start token. For instance, tokenizing a word **a** has start token `3` which is an empty string with `gtr-t5-large` model.

```
model_name: str ="gtr-t5-large"
tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
     f'sentence-transformers/{model_name}'
)

text = "a"
sentence_t5_tokenizer(text)['input_ids']
-----
[3, 9, 1]
```

```
tokenizer.batch_decode(tokenizer(text)['input_ids'])
-----
['', 'a', '</s>']
```

But tokenizing **Madame** does not have the start token. Then slicing tokens with `[1:-1]` will lose the first token.

```
text = "Madame"
sentence_t5_tokenizer(text)['input_ids']
-----
[27328, 1]
```

```
tokenizer.batch_decode(tokenizer(text)['input_ids'])
-----
['Madame', '</s>']
```

Below shows naively slicing with `[1:-1]` will chop off the first word.

```
from langchain.text_splitter import (
    SentenceTransformersTokenTextSplitter
)

splitter = SentenceTransformersTokenTextSplitter(
    model_name="gtr-t5-large",
    chunk_overlap=0
)


text: str = "Madame Speaker, Vice President Biden, members of Congress, distinguished guests, and fellow Americans:"
sentence_trf_splitter.split_text(text)
-----
# 'Madame' is lost, if run it again on the result, then 'Speaker' gets lost.
['Speaker, Vice President Biden, members of Congress, distinguished guests, and fellow Americans:']
```